# Counting 2+3 and 4 over a beat of 4 at the same time

Tags: piano, meter, polyrhythm

I'm rearranging a piece of mine from 12/8 to 4/4. This works pretty fine for the harmony since those were arpeggiated chords, 4 groups of 3. But I notice the melody is rather complicated to transfer to 4/4, and I've found out that what works best (musically) is that it alternates between 2/4 and 3/4. But this is only for the melody, not for the harmony which is still 4/4.
Now since this is for piano, obviously I'm wondering whether people can count like that: 2 different rhythms at the same time (I know I can't, but I can't play piano anyway) I.e. is this playable?

[image]

Or will pianists want to kill me?

Answer (score 8):

Three against two is really easy for any experienced musician.
If you were going to write seven against five, most people would have trouble playing it accurately.

Comment: What I'd kill over is the inaccurate spacing of the note heads.

Comment: Hahaha, yes, that is worth killing over.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- - what's wrong with them? Beats 1 and 3 align in both clefs, and the triplet on top has a little gap so the last crotchet can be seen to fit where it should.

Comment: @Tim The note heads aren't evenly spaced, and particularly when trying to demonstrate a polyrhythm, note heads _in a group_ (such as a single triplet bracket) should be spaced consistently.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- - I understand that. However, for the less experienced players, I feel the way it's shown is more helpful - it shows *when* things get played. We'll agree to differ! And I have a pedant degree...

Comment: @Tim Note that I'm not saying that _the notes in both hands_ should be identically spaced; I'm saying that _the notes in each hand_ should be identically spaced. This mixed spacing _obscures_ the relationship you mention because the first two triplets look "faster".

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- that's my point. Not faster - all three are equal, and since the second will be played somewhere in between the last two crotchets (l.h.), it helps pictorially. Agree to differ.

Answer (score 3):

Needs a little bit of looking at, more for which notes are played than where they all fit between each other, but any player from grade VI upwards would manage that, and pros wouldn't even get a small weapon out.